# Xcode build error - "Implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_key’ is invalid in C99"

Tags: ios, sqlite, compiler-errors, cocoapods, sqlcipher

I am modularising a large iOS app lets say, `MyAppWithDatabase` into two modules (i.e. projects). So I will have one main project `MyApp` as a host and a linked `MyDataPlatform` as a framework under same workspace `MyApp.xcworkspace`. When `SQLCipher` [pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SQLCipher) was integrated for target `MyAppWithDatabase` it worked fine, but as all of the database related codes are being moved into `MyDataPlatform` framework in refactoring, I want to integrate `SQLCipher` pod only for the framework to keep internal encryption mechanism abstract from host app. Now, when I have integrated for framework it started producing below build error.

> Implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_key’ is invalid in C99

**Note** that this issue is being produced from one statement of `MyApp`s source code as a warning but Xcode build treating it as error,

```
sqlite3_key(_db, [password UTF8String], (int)password.length);
```

I have the above line still remaining in `MyApp` because it takes time to move database related codes gradually into `MyDataPlatform` and I assume the SQLCipher headers are still supposed to be available in host app as the related framework in linked.

I have gone through many proposed [solutions](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/ios-11-xcode-issue-implicit-declaration-of-function-sqlite3-key-is-invalid-in-c99/2198) on the Internet but none of them worked for my case. I doubt most of the solutions are about integrating `SQLCipher` for host app only. What should I do when I get the error for framework in my case?

Below is the structure of my pod file (after refactored),

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  # ...

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'MyDataPlatform' do
  project 'MyDataPlatform/MyDataPlatform.xcodeproj'
  pod 'SQLCipher', '~>3.4.2'

  #https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/ios-11-xcode-issue-implicit-declaration-of-function-sqlite3-key-is-invalid-in-c99/2198/53
  post_install do | installer |
    print "SQLCipher: link Pods/Headers/sqlite3.h"
    system "mkdir -p Pods/Headers/Private && ln -s ../../SQLCipher/sqlite3.h Pods/Headers/Private"
  end
end
```

Previously `SQLCipher` was integrated under `MyAppWithDatabase` i.e.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyAppWithDatabase' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SQLCipher', '~>3.4.2'
  # ...

  target 'MyAppWithDatabaseTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved after defining `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC` in application's,

```
MyApp -> Build Settings -> Other C Flags
```

Another solution also works after adding `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1` in application's,

```
MyApp -> Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by SPACEs in my project's pathname. The sqlite 'make' script that should generate the sqlite3.c at compilation time seems to trip when there are SPACEs in the sqlcipher library's pathname. I temporarily removed the SPACEs from the pathname and compilation worked.